# How to get unique value from aws cli when used jq query with contains

Tags: jq, aws-cli

When I run the below command I get this

```
aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster $clusterName   --tasks $tasks | jq -r '.tasks[]| select(.group | contains( "'$serviceName'")).containerInstanceArn'
```

output:

> arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:123456:container-instance/my-cluster-dev/ed6292913912344553e236d96cc4fdf7

> arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:123456:container-instance/my-cluster-dev/ed6292913912344553e236d96cc4fdf7

I tried something like this

```
aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster $clusterName   --tasks $tasks | jq '.tasks[]| select(.group | contains( "'$serviceName'")).containerInstanceArn'| jq '.| unique'
```

but get error

> jq: error (at :1): Cannot iterate over string ("arn:aws:ec...)

> jq: error (at :2): Cannot iterate over string ("arn:aws:ec...)

what is the proper way to get unique value when using `select` with `contains` so that only one vaule come out as the output.

**Updated with json output**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "connectivityAt": "2021-01-04T08:01:14.585000+05:30",
            "containerInstanceArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:123456:container-instance/my-cluster-dev/ed6292913912344553e236d96cc4fdf7",
            "group": "service:cb-myservice1-api-dev-ecs-cb-myservice1-api-man-1839134",
            "version": 2
        },
        {
            "connectivityAt": "2020-12-30T16:47:48.408000+05:30",
            "containerInstanceArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:123456:container-instance/my-cluster-dev/d5d2a0608134533347563d8383e",
            "group": "service:cb-myservice2-api-dev-ecs-cb-myservice2-api-man-1816014",
            "version": 2
        },
        {
            "connectivityAt": "2021-01-04T08:02:35.266000+05:30",
            "containerInstanceArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:123456:container-instance/my-cluster-dev/ed6292913912344553e236d96cc4fdf7",
            "group": "service:cb-myservice1-api-staging-ecs-cb-myservice1-api-man-1839116",

            "version": 2
        }
    ],
    "failures": []
}
```

Comment: What does the json that you're working with look like?

Comment: @JeffMercado Please see above with updated json

Comment: Please review the [mcve] guidelines.  What is the value of $serviceName ?

Answer (score 1):

`unique` expects an array as input, so you could tweak your query as follows:

```
  [.tasks[] | select(.group | contains( "'$serviceName'")).containerInstanceArn]
  | unique[]
```

Note, however, that it would almost surely be better to pass in the value of `$serviceName` using the jq command-line option `--arg`; it might also be worthwhile checking that you really do want to use `contains`, which can easily cause surprises because of its complex semantics.

Comment: Then above script did not work I tried cat myjson.json | jq '.tasks[]|select(.group | contains("cb-myservice1-api")).containerInstanceArn|unique[]'

Comment: @kumar - You are missing some square brackets. You might like to try copy-and-paste.